# Prove these two characterizations of the tangent space are equivalent

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I have also [asked this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/355535/150898).

$\DeclareMathOperator{\A}{\mathbb{A}}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$

Let $X=V(f_1,\dots,f_m) \subseteq \A^n$ be an affine variety over $\C$ cut out by polynomials $f_1,\dots, f_m$. Define the *tangent space to $X$ at p*

$$
\Theta_p=V(\{d_p f: f \in I(X)\})=V(d_p f_1,\dots, d_p f_m),
$$
where $d_p f (x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\delta f}{\delta x_i}(p)x_i$.

I think this should be equal to the set

$$
\Theta'_p=\{x \in \A^n : \text{There exists a smooth curve $\gamma: \C \rightarrow X\subseteq \A^n$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=x$.}\}
$$

**I think I can show that $\Theta_p' \subseteq \Theta_p$:**

If $x \in \Theta_p'$, then for all $f \in I(X)$,

\begin{align}
d_p f (x)&=\sum_i \frac{\delta f}{\delta x_i}(p)x_i\\
&=\sum_i \frac{\delta f}{\delta x_i}(\gamma(0))\gamma'(0)_{i}\\
&=(f \circ \gamma)'(0)\\
&=0,
\end{align}
where the third line is the chain rule and the last line follows from the fact that $\gamma(t) \in X$ for all $t \in \C$, so $(f \circ \gamma)(t)=0$ for all $t \in \C$, so $(f \circ \gamma)'(0)=0$. So $x \in \Theta_p$.

How do we show the other direction (if it is true)?

Comment: Note that when you have a submersion (and that is the case for a nice 0-set of polynomials), the kernel of the differentials gives exactly the tangent space. For, compare dimensions and explain why your calculation gives a necessary condition.

Comment: @R.Alexandre Thanks for the hint, dimension comparison is a good idea. How do we show $\dim(\Theta_p) \leq \dim(\Theta'_p)$?

Comment: Count directly the dimension of each. You have $m$ polynomials $f$, that should give you a dimension $n-m$.